# assembler code error

Tags: assembly, numbers, tasm

```
 .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 100h
    .DATA
Var1 dd 2
PromptStr DB 'is perfect',13,10,'$'
ans dd 2
count dd 2
     .CODE
     .386
Begin:
    MOV AX,@DATA     ; DS can be written to only through a register
    MOV DS,AX        ; Set DS to point to data segment    

dobody1:
    JMP TestNext1
dobody2:
    CMP ans,32513
    JA finish
    MOV EAX,ans
    MOV EBX,2
    MUL EBX
    MOV ans,EAX
    DEC count
TestNext1:
    CMP var1,2
    JE check2
    MOV EAX,count
    CMP Var1,EAX
    JNE dobody2
check2 :
    MOV EAX,ans
    MOV EBX,2
    MUL EBX
    INC EAX
    MOV EBX,ans
    MUL EBX
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21h
    MOV ans,2
    MOV count,2
    DEC Var1
    JMP dobody1

finish :

MOV AH,4Ch       ; Set terminate option for int 21h
INT  21h       ; Return to DOS (terminate program)
END Begin
```

i`m trying to print the perfect numbers with assembler tasm and i get an unexpected enf of file encountered error !!!

Comment: I don't quite get why your code jumps around so much.

Comment: it`s finding the number by 
(2^(n-1))*((2^n)-1)

Comment: Compiler error? Doesn't it has to have an 'end' at the end (plus maybe an extra blank line)?

Comment: it have end begin !
and no there is no need for extra blank line

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ends` before `end begin`.  Not sure if it is a big deal, but `.386` should not be in the code segment, but before `.MODEL`.